# Flex 4.10 new features

Tags: list, apache-flex, flex4, flash-builder

I have installed Flex 4.10.0 SDK for Flash Builder 4.7 (tried both MacOS and Windows) using the new [Apache Flex SDK Installer](http://flex.apache.org/installer.html) and loved how smoothly it has worked:

[image]

Also I'm excited that someone is still working on the Flex SDK (thank you!) - because for quite some time it looked abandoned.

**My 3 questions:**

1. Does anybody have a list of the (supposedly over fifteen?) new Spark components? I have only noticed one sofar: `mx.controls.Alert` -> [spark.components.Alert](http://flex.apache.org/asdoc/spark/components/Alert.html). (And I have noticed that `spark.utils.MultiDPIBitmapSource` supports `source480dpi` which is great).
2. Does anybody know, if there is a fix for the `spark.components.List` not remembering its scrolling position? Because currently [in my Flex game](https://www.facebook.com/appcenter/video-preferans) with 2 Lists updated by server I have to use custom skin and data group as explained [in this nice blog](http://flex4examples.wordpress.com/2010/06/18/flex-4-list-remembering-verticalscrollposition/).
3. Currently to scroll a `spark.components.List` to a bottom I have to use [the following hack](http://flexponential.com/2011/02/13/scrolling-to-the-bottom-of-a-spark-list/) and wonder if that issue has been approached too?

   ```
   public static function scrollToBottom(list:List):void {
       // update the verticalScrollPosition to the end of the List
       // virtual layout may require us to validate a few times
       var delta:Number = 0;
       var count:int = 0;

       while (count++ < 10) {
           list.validateNow();
           delta = list.layout.getVerticalScrollPositionDelta(NavigationUnit.END);
           list.layout.verticalScrollPosition += delta;

           if (delta == 0)
               break;
       }
   }
   ```

**UPDATE:**

For the issue #3 I've created a [JIRA #33660](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLEX-33660) with a test case and screenshot attached. There were already similar bug reports, but they were closed by Adobe.

**UPDATE 2:**

For the issue #2 I haven't been able to create a simple test case yet, but I definetely see that problem in my app (the link is above, do not want to spam), where 2 Lists are updated via TCP socket by server.

Here is my current test case (not really demoing the problem), maybe someone can improve it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
               applicationComplete="init()">

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import flash.utils.setInterval;
            private function init():void {
                setInterval(add, 1000);
            }

            private function add():void {
                var pos:int = Math.floor(myAC.length * Math.random());
                myAC.addItemAt({label: Math.random()}, pos);
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <s:List id="myList" width="100%" height="100%">
        <s:dataProvider>
            <s:ArrayCollection id="myAC" />
        </s:dataProvider>
    </s:List>

    <s:controlBarContent>
        <s:Button id="myButton" label="Add number" click="add()" />
    </s:controlBarContent>

</s:Application>
```

Comment: All bug fixes and experimental components are listed in the [release notes](https://github.com/apache/flex-sdk/blob/develop/RELEASE_NOTES). If those bugs aren't registered in [JIRA](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLEX) yet, you should do so; or fix it yourself and supply a patch ;)

Comment: Seems to me the list of new components is right there under "Experimental Components". I don't think there's 15 though (unless you count the subcomponents). You can see the code here: https://github.com/apache/flex-sdk/tree/develop/frameworks/projects/experimental/src/spark/components

Comment: Not sure if it is just me, but I cannot get the GitHub links to work currently. Here is the Release Notes that the Apache site links to directly. http://mirror.olnevhost.net/pub/apache/flex/4.10.0/RELEASE_NOTES

Comment: `<s:ProgressBar ... />` is in the doc too, but gives compile error...

Comment: They're experimental components of course. Again, you can help out by filing a bug report.

Comment: I've created https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLEX-33660 (for issue #3) and https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLEX-33661 (for ProgressBar). For the issue #2 I haven't been able to create a simple test case yet.

Comment: Re JIRA issues closed by Adobe just post to the list with the JIRA number and we'll reopen them if they are still an issue.

Comment: BTW Support for 120 and 640 dpi bitmaps/mobile skins are just being added as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In reply to Part 1, I found a [Release Notes](https://dist.apache.org/repos/dist/dev/flex/sdk/4.10.0/rc3/RELEASE_NOTES) file that mentions the following new Spark components:

Accordion, DataAccordion, InlineScroller, CallOut, CallOutButton, Alert, ColorPicker, MenuBar, Menu, and ProgressBar.

Also several new layouts:
AccordionLayout, CarouselLayout, CoverflowLayout, StackLayout (and more).